# Python how to shorten If else condition

Tags: python, performance, if-statement

How can I shorten this condition pattern;

```
if xconditon == "a text":
 Avariable = Yvariable

elif xcondition == "b text":
 Bvariable = Yvariable

elif xcondition == "c text":
 Cvariable = Yvariable
```

condition goes on like this, there is a pattern so I am searching for ways to shorten this code.

I'm looking for **best** way to reduce the code clutter, also improving the performance, looked for Python equivalent *C++ auto*, thought of using 2D lists but using dictionary seems better.

Comment: I can't think of an easy way to simplify it. Maybe you shouldn't use separate variables, use a dictionary whose key is the value of `xcondition`

Comment: It sounds like you are creating variable variables. You should take a look at answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use different variables, use a dictionary.

```
mydict[xcondition] = Yvariable
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the list of conditions and their corresponding variable names if you really have a lot of them, for just three it doesnt make sense though. I made an example:

```
list = [
"a":{"letter":"a","condition":"conditionA", variable:"variableA"}
"b":{"letter":"b","condition":"conditionB", variable:"variableB"}
]

for i in list:
    if conditionX == i["condition"]:
        list["letter"]["variable"] = variableX
```